# How to troubleshoot Group Policy with a disabled cmd

Tags: group-policy

On a large domain with many terminal servers, I'm implementing software installation for a handful of users. They can login to all terminal servers through a connection broker server so the software is installed into their userprofile by Group Policy using User configuration -> Software deployment.

Something is setup wrong and my software is not installed, but we have cmd disabled, so I can't do a `gpresult /v` to see if it is even applying and where things are going wrong. Other policies are applying so it should work but it doesn't.

What is the way to go about this? We have the various GPO settings in one GPO object, so I can't just enable cmd for a testuser while the rest is in effect.

Comment: You might want to see if PowerShell prompt might work.  Typically would throw the one machine into it's own GPO object.

Comment: @ramhound No, we disabled Powershell too. But my colleague came with a great way. I'll post it as an answer but I'll wait with accepting my answer in case someone has a better way.

Comment: Did you try entering the command in Task Manager? File, New Task, and enable Create Task with Admin Privileges.   If it will run on your system, it can pull up gpedit.msc.

Comment: @John which command? the installer or the gpresult? Also, Task Manager is also disabled.

Comment: I used gpedit.msc to see . gpresult disappears the same way as the method you used. It looks to be the same underlying method.,

Comment: I did assist you be a +1 Upvote as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though cmd is disabled, you can still enter commands in the addressbar of explorer.

You can type in cmd in there but that will obviously give the cmd is disabled message.

You can however run gpresult in there and it will work. The only problem is that the screen goes away when its done, so you will have to make it export the result to a html file. Although I prefer the output of gpresult /v over the html report, at least its something.

To make a report, type in: `gpresult /r result.html` in explorer and it will place the result.html in the same folder as you are currently viewing in explorer.

Answer (score -1):

If you have PowerShell/WinRM enabled on the machine, you can connect to it remotely over the same network using [Connect-PsSession](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/connect-pssession?view=powershell-7.1). Alternatively you can use [PsExec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) to remote into it if you have permissions.

Another trick is if you copy `conhost.exe` from the System32 folder on to a flash drive and rename it to something else, you can usually open it right up. It depends on how you have CMD restricted, though. Remoting in as mentioned above might be the best idea.

Comment: so... I'm logged in as a normal user, and I want to test how the group policy was applied. How is Enter-PSSession (not connect-pssession) going to help me here, as it is clearly an administrative command, giving me a powershell interface as admin user? I mean, I can just login to the server as admin and do things there. I will look into the conhost trick, but I'm fairly sure that is also blocked.

Comment: You can run commands as another user using the runas command.  Also look into gpresult.

Comment: I have to vote your answer down... You do not seem to understand the question.

Comment: Perhaps not. I would suggest you simply create an exception for a test user in Group Policy so you can test with cmd, then later remove it after confirming.  There's really no way around that other than the conhost trick.

Comment: See my answer, I came to something that does work, The conhost trick may still work, I have to test that. Creating an exception in GPO is not going to work, because the entire GPO is disabled, and it is exactly that what I need to troubleshoot. I am building a GPO and if I disable the GPO for that user, how can I test it for that user then?

Comment: I copied conhost.exe from the system32 folder to the desktop and renamed it, I start it, I see the mouse cursor change briefly but no command prompt appears. So that doesn't work either.